# Microsoft To Do My Day view not showing overdue tasks

Tags: microsoft, to-do

Why My Day view in Microsoft To Do not showing overdue tasks? suppose I worked yesterday on My Day view and I didn't complete a task. Why don't I find it the incomplete task in "My Day" tomorrow? Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The post
[To-Do Overdue tasks](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/to-do-overdue-tasks/m-p/265600)
is about this problem, where several frustrated users post their
discontent with the problem.

The user named "Coffeeling" explained the problem :

> My Day's point is to be an intentional list that you curate yourself,
> not something that gets populated automatically. The thought is that
> we often have too many tasks, so the idea is that to have a handpicked
> list that's small enough to be achievable and feels like you can make
> progress against.
>
> At least for me, I can add stuff in bulk from Planned to My Day - just
> right click a bucket's title (in your case, Earlier) and it has an
> "Add tasks to My Day" button.
>
> Also, My Day's Suggestions panel (press the lightbulb at the top)
> shows you overdue tasks which are easy to add to My Day.

User "cfortinleung" also wrote :

> Easy fix for this: use the list "Planned" instead of "My Day".  This will show overdue tasks, tasks for today, and you can scroll down to see future tasks as well.

Comment: I was thinking of moving to another to do list app just because of this reason. It is really important not to lose overdue tasks.